# SISSDB - writing custom message

Tags: database, ssis, etl

I am using SSIS 2012 - project deployment model, utilizing the out of the box SSISDB logging.

However, I was wondering how to log custom messages to the SSISDB, i.e. "hello world" when the package start or when a certain event is raised. Is this possible? 
Or do I have to fallback to a custom log table, which seems to defeat the advantage of the SSISDB logging.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Of course it is. What message would you like to log? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136054.aspx

This is an example from a Script Task (Control Flow)

```
        bool fireAgain = false;
        Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "Test", "I am the description", string.Empty, 0, ref fireAgain);
```

This is an example from a Script Component (Data Flow)

```
    bool fireAgain = false;
    ComponentMetaData.FireInformation(0, "Test too", "I am data flow description", string.Empty, 0, ref fireAgain);
```

You can then look in your reports or write custom queries against `catalog.operation_messages` in SSISDB. When we were loading our data warehouse, if I found employee ids that the data didn't support, I'd fire off OnInformation events with the words Research in the title and then parse out the bits I needed (employee id and the date).

Comment: For a SSIS controlflow I would like to audit/log something like: 

SMTP mail task:
- Which person has been mailed
- Full name of the attachment

For a file loop:
- Counting the files which have been processed/picked up in folder.

And so on..

Had already tried DTS.LOG, but it did not provide any context in the SSISDB reports(no container path, no classification of message etc.) 

What I wondering, If you choose to use the Oninformation log strategy, is the script task the only way to call this method,eventually ending up with a several script tasks in a control/dataflow just to log.